# How does one cancel a system groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins

In Jenkins I have a system groovy script build step. Is there any way to cancel a long running script, or to have some code within the system groovy script which can tell whether its build has been cancelled?

Comment: Related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070055/jenkins-job-running-system-groovy-script-how-to-respond-to-user-kill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins will interrupt the thread which is running the script when you cancel the build.

So you can either manually [check](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()) the thread's interrupt status and abort your script at certain points, e.g.

```
if (Thread.currentThread().interrupted()) {
  throw new InterruptedException()
}
```

Or you can let Groovy do that for you by including the [ThreadInterrupt](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/ThreadInterrupt.html) annotation in your script, e.g.

```
@groovy.transform.ThreadInterrupt
```

Also make sure that none of your catch blocks will swallow an InterruptedException.

Comment: I seem to be observing significant impact on Jenkins performance simply by using that annotation. Maybe it's a coincidence, but it did happen twice in a row....

Comment: So, I think that there is more to this than meets the eye. If your system groovy script is launching threads, you need to do something about them prior to exiting. I am not sure how to capture all of them yet, but I guess I will learn and find out..